# How to cut string="Domain_12345_20180821230101.dat" into 12345_20180821 in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Provided that this sting is dynamic. If it is as `Domain_1234_20180821230101.dat` then I want `1234_20180821`. How can I do that?

I.e., when `Domain_12_20180821230101.dat` then I want output as `12_20180821`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A primitive solution that works for the examples you gave would be:

```
grep -oP '[0-9]+_[0-9]{8}' <<< "$string"
```

This will extract any substring consisting of a variable-length number, followed by an underscore, followed by an 8-digit number if present, else return nothing.

You can find more infos to help you understand this command and adjust it to your requirements if necessary under `grep --help` and https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.

Comment: Thanx @Sam but how can I store it into some other variable

Comment: `some_other_variable=$(grep -oP '[0-9]+_[0-9]{8}' <<< "$string")`. see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

Comment: Thank you So much @Sam It worked as Expected.....